# Sprite Kit random positions

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to position my 1 nodes at random between 3 Points. Lets say these Positions are :

```
1: CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - 123.5  , y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) * 2.5)
2: CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) , y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) * 2.5)
3: CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + 123.5  , y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) * 2.5)
```

My code:

```
let arabaHareketi = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -self.frame.size.height * 2,  duration: 2.5)
let turuncuYapılışı = SKTexture(imageNamed: "turuncu")
let turuncu = SKSpriteNode(texture: turuncuYapılışı)
    turuncu.size = CGSizeMake(104, 204)
    turuncu.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - 123.5 + pipeOffSet  , y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) * 2.5)
    turuncu.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: turuncu.size)
    turuncu.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    turuncu.runAction(arabaHareketi)
    turuncu.zPosition = 21
    self.addChild(turuncu)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please explain what is not working.  What results or error messages are you getting?

Comment: it's not an error. i want  position my 1 nodes at random between 3 Points. sorry My bad english

Comment: @Nazım Any update about my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `arc4random()` to get a random number.  Get the remainder by running `% 3` on it.  Then use an if statement system to check the remainders (which in this case will be 0, 1, or 2).  Here's some code for this:

```
let index = arc4random() % 3;
if index == 0 {
    turuncu.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - 123.5  , y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) * 2.5)
} else if index == 1 {
    turuncu.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) , y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) * 2.5)
} else {
    turuncu.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + 123.5  , y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) * 2.5)
}
```

If you want to add additional possibilities, take the middle `else if` statement, and continue to chain it.  Something like this:

```
if condition1 {
} else if condition2 {
} else if condition3 {
...
} else if conditionN {
} else {
}
```

Make sure put in a higher number for the remainder operator if you choose to have more conditions.

Comment: thank you for answers but it's not work. 
error: use of local variable "turuncu" before its declaration

Comment: @Nazim Gilderman's suggestions seems legit enough. The problem that throws up that error is merely that you put his given code somewhere ***above*** the declaration of the variable. The code ***YOU*** gave shows the declaration. Make sure that you put Gilderman's code below that.

Comment: Correct.  You did not say what you were assigning the `CGPoint` to, so I used `turuncu`.  Use whatever node's name that you are trying to assign.  From your code, I would guess a node having to do with a pipe.

Comment: @Nazım You're welcome.  If this solved your problem, please mark as solved.